# Can I make SWT table headers span to make a super header

Tags: java, swt, tableviewer

I would like to create a table, where I can have a 'super' header spanning over more columns in order to group the columns.
In the example below 'Balance' is a header for 'Income' and 'Spending'.

To solve this issue, headers must be able to span both horizontally and vertically as 'Year' and 'Comments' are spanning 2 'rows' in the header. Is this possible with SWT?

[image: Table header where Balance is heading Income and Spending]

Comment: No, not with Table or TableViewer. I believe Eclipse Nebula [tag:nattable] can do this - https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/

Comment: Thanks :)
I believe you are right, I haven't been able to find anything that could help me.
My best solution is to color the background of dependent columns, and at the same time give the headers a tooltip text that describes the interdependence.
Not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question.

A convenient way to do this is to use the NatTable framework, which can form up to 3 levels of headers.
Start by following this link:
[Nebula NatTable](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/index.php)

Comment: Since NatTable 1.6 there is a new performance column grouping API. This is the preferred way to create column groups and does not have the limitation with regards to the number of header levels.